# ASP.Net EntityDataSource vs. EF4 Code First

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm attempting to create a web app that works with business data models, pretty much a simple CRUD setup. I'd like to leverage the inbuilt CRUD support in ASP.Net controls like the ListView, but the EntityDataSource doesn't support the Code First connection string.

Do I have to develop a custom DataSource to achieve this? How can I achieve this native databinding support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to develop custom data source you just need `ObjectDataSource` and custom object executing your CRUD operations used by this data source.

Comment: Can you give an example or link or something? Otherwise your answer does nothing for me.

Comment: The MSDN itself contains example of [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx70zk47.aspx). If you understand ASP.NET at least little bit and EF as well it should be piece of cake for you. If you don't then you should start with some tutorial. If you want example show what you did so far = make smallest possible reproducible example of your problem and what doesn't work so that we see that you are not just another "give me some codez plz".